# Need a office 2007 Macro for the below situation?

Tags: excel

Here is the situation: We have a mobile app which sends the data entered/captured by user through email to any email client selected by the user. Data/attachments consists of one .csv(excel file) and .jpg file(may be 1to3 pics).
Basically we have automated the manual report filing (before automation, folks use manual report filing using normal/manual paper filing technique).Now i want to create a good looking report in ms word or in excel(if later is not possible) from what i have sent(attachments)to the email.
Few links to give you guys a hint about the target doc file and excel file with attachment.

Excel file: http://i1117.photobucket.com/albums/k596/hitmanx07/Excel.png
Doc file: http://i1117.photobucket.com/albums/k596/hitmanx07/Doc.png

Need a automated solution so that every time user downloads the data from email he/she could possibly change the downloaded excel file into a doc(see attached).

Hope i'm clear

mrana...

Comment: Ok..guys i have solved this issue. :)

Comment: Note that you can answer you own question (it is even [highly recommended](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)) and accept it. This way, you can share your knowledge with the community and kind of *close* the question.

Comment: Sorry I didn't have time to look at your issue but I am glad you eventually solved it by yourself. The point I am raising here is that you can share your solution so that it will help further users.

Comment: @JMax I just checked and submitted the sol.

Comment: thanks. There is a small delay before you can accept your own answer but you can find any of your question back in your profile (click wherever on your nickname)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for above:
Ms-office Excel's Macros is the solution for this issue. Basically Macros work in such a manner that what steps user performs on excel to solve the issue have been recorded by macros and then user can perform same task within seconds which if done manually could take so many time by use of that recorded macros.
So basically its an automation technique.
Please use this link to see how to deal with all these things.

http://www.csus.edu/training/handouts/workshops/Excel07pivot&macro.pdf

gracius.